# Is it possible to use external IFC exporter in DA4R?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I need to use IFC for Revit library [SourceForge link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ifcexporter/). 
Can i override the version that is built in?
 I mean using Document.Export(path,IFCExportOptions).

How can i use it in DA4R app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting question, can I know why do you want to override the built in version? is there any limitation? Maybe that is also a good request for us to improve or fix in Revit. And Revit Design Automation engine currently supports Revit 2018.3, 2019.2 and 2020.2, are they all not working for you?

Revit Design Automation includes the support for IFC last April at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/change_history/revit_release_notes/, I am not an IFC expert but I don't think there is a way for developer to specify the version in DA4R. But to override the current behavior to export IFC, in theory, you can achieve that within your Revit plugin on DA4R, but you need to customize all the export to IFC functionality within your Revit AppBundle(make sure no namespace conflict with current Ifc export library), you may also need to package all the dependent DLLs within the package to make it work, then upload as AppBundle, define an activity then post a workitem.

Please also notice that the limitation of Revit AppBundle size is 100M by default at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/quotas/, you may need to override the size by checking https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/servicelimits-owner-PUT/

Comment: https://www.bim42.com/2017/09/using-the-revit-ifc-export-in-your-own-add-on/
I'd like to use it like in this article, some features are not exist yet in Revit.

Comment: Confirmed with our engineer, we never tried, but in theory Yes, you can override the export behavior within your Design Automation for Revit engine! All the customization work should be done within your AppBundle, you may also package all the dependent DLLs within the package to make it work. But please notice that the limitation of Revit AppBundle size is 100M by default at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/quotas/, you may need to override the size with https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/servicelimits-owner-PUT/

Comment: Just happened to see this thread: We can override IFC addin version used in DA, and I shared the instructions here: https://github.com/yiskang/aps-revit-ifc-exporter-appbundle